# Uncountable sets unrelated to real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question may be a little general, but are there any other examples of uncountable sets except those related to real numbers?

Comment: The set of subsets (i.e. *power-set*) of every *countable* infinite set.

Comment: The set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is always an interesting example.

Comment: I like the [first uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set

$$ \{(x_n): x_n \in \{0,1\} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N\}$$

is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many.

The fist one to come to mind is the *first uncountable ordinal*. It is so unrelated to the real numbers that trying to come up with a useful relationship at all between the two was allegedly what drove Georg Cantor mad. There are, of course, any ordinal above that one as well.

As mentioned in the comments, the power-set of *any* infinite set is uncountably infinite.